# retrieving the client source port on a HTTPD -> Tomcat setting

Tags: tomcat, apache

I have an httpd server configured to handle HTTPS connections and forward the connections to a Tomcat (via http or ajp) where the requests are processed. One of the requirements I have in the Tomcat server is to log the remote port number of each request. If I hit the Tomcat directly, retrieving the remote port number is straight forward and we are currently doing it using the `getRemotePort()` function (HttpServletRequest).

However, since I'm doing a reverse proxy (forwarding HTTPS requests via HTTP/AJP) a new connection will be created and I'll always get the remote port (and remote IP for that matter) for the connection from my httpd server to tomcat (except when I use AJP. In this case the remote server IP info comes correctly).

I've tried different configurations on httpd, like:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

or

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
```

I also played a little bit with RewriteRules, but couldn't make things work.

Reading httpd documentation, mod_proxy offers request header information for things like  `X-Forwarded-Host`, `X-Forwarded-For`, etc. But there is no info about source port.

I've [even found a bug](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-bugs/200304.mbox/%3C20030401191204.13726.qmail@nagoya.betaversion.org%3E), where apparently a `X-Forwarded-Port` attribute was added to the proxy request header, but that code doesn't seem to have made to the main line/branch.

So, in summary, how can I retrieve the source port of the client (not the reverse proxy) when HTTPD is forwarding requests to Tomcat?

Comment: So you get the remote ip address but not the port ? Also, can you pass on the version numbers of tomcat/httpd. The httpd bug that you found was for version 1.3

Comment: Hi Kevin. I'm using Apache httpd v 2.2.3 and Tomcat 5.5

Comment: When I configure the httpd server with `ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/`, the tomcat request contains the following headers: x-forwarded-for=, x-forwarded-host= and, x-forwarded-server. If I configure the httpd server with `ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8081/`, I don't get those headers.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a request header called **X-Forwarded-SourcePort** with mod_rewrite + mod_headers

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_PORT:%{REMOTE_PORT},NE]
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-SourcePort %{REMOTE_PORT}e
```

Apache will forward the request with the client source port to the backend server, so you can get the X-Forwarded-SourcePort request header from your application.

Comment: added, if using vhosts, added these in each <Virtualhosts> section,   RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using the mod_rewrite module

In a [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) you can specify server variables in the *Substitution* String as stated in the documentation

```
In addition to plain text, the Substition string can include

    back-references ($N) to the RewriteRule pattern
    back-references (%N) to the last matched RewriteCond pattern
    server-variables as in rule condition test-strings (%{VARNAME})
```

One of these variables is `REMOTE_PORT`.
You can then rewrite your URL and pass it as an URL parameter to to your Tomcat servlet call e.g.

`http://url.to.tomcat/mycontext?remoteport=${REMOTE_PORT}`